# зацикливание в Chrome при редиректе (PHP - JS)

Tags: php, javascript, html, браузер

Проблема: периодически появляется зацикливание в СHROME.
Есть страница поиска на сайте. При вводе пользователем символов на латинице идет их транслитация, т.е перевод на русс-укр символы. В portoble CHROME идет зацикливание и иногда в обычном Chrome. В FF IE работает нормально. В чем может быть причина?
Код: (файл - html, кодировка 1251)

```
<?php 
preg_match_all("/[a-zA-Z]/",$search_sp, $out);
if( (count($out[0]) > 0) && (strlen($search_sp) > 3)   ){
    $trans_sph = translitSph(strtolower($search_sp), $lng);
    echo '<script> window.location.href = "' . SITEURL . '/search/?search=' . urlencode($trans_sph) . '" </script>';
}
?>
/// html html .................
<?php
function translitSph($search_sp,$lng){
    if($lng == 1){
    $translit = array(
                    "q"=>"й", "w"=>"ц", "e"=>"у", "r"=>"к", 
                    "t"=>"е", "y"=>"н", "u"=>"г", "i"=>"ш", "o"=>"щ", 
                    "p"=>"з", "["=>"х", "]"=>"ъ", "a"=>"ф", "s"=>"ы", 
                    "d"=>"в", "f"=>"а", "g"=>"п", "h"=>"р", "j"=>"о", 
                    "k"=>"л", "l"=>"д", ";"=>"ж", "'"=>"э", "z"=>"я", 
                    "x"=>"ч", "c"=>"с", "v"=>"м", "b"=>"и", "n"=>"т", 
                    "m"=>"ь", ","=>"б", "."=>"ю"
                    );
    }else {
    $translit = array(
                    "q"=>"й", "w"=>"ц", "e"=>"у", "r"=>"к", 
                    "t"=>"е", "y"=>"н", "u"=>"г", "i"=>"ш", "o"=>"щ", 
                    "p"=>"з", "["=>"х", "]"=>"ї", "a"=>"ф", "s"=>"і", 
                    "d"=>"в", "f"=>"а", "g"=>"п", "h"=>"р", "j"=>"о", 
                    "k"=>"л", "l"=>"д", ";"=>"ж", "'"=>"є", "z"=>"я", 
                    "x"=>"ч", "c"=>"с", "v"=>"м", "b"=>"и", "n"=>"т", 
                    "m"=>"ь", ","=>"б", "."=>"ю", "\\"=>"ґ"
                    );
    }
    $word = strtr($search_sp, $translit);
    //return $word = iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1251',$word);
    return $word ;
}
?>
```

Итог:
Входящий результат : ghbdtn;Ожидаемый: привет; Результат : привет (IE, Opera, FF, Chrome) Результат в portable Chrome : зацикливание; While trying to retrieve the URL: test.com/search/?search=%2525252525252525252525252525252525.‌​..........

Comment: Что такое `$search_sp` ?

Comment: запрос-пользователя. Пр.: укрUkrкыrs

Comment: Он не из `$_GET['search']` берётся?

Comment: да из GET. Проблема с кодировкой?

Comment: Здесь-то в функции у вас utf-8 кодировка...

Comment: На каких входных строках идёт зацикливание? Это может быть опечатка(вида `"с"=>"с"` с двумя латинскими c)?

Comment: Странно, но на др. браузерах все ок.

Comment: 2 недели были проблемы. И сейчас сама исчезла - очень странно. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: А всё потому, что нужно тестами покрывать)

Comment: В репозитории есть диффы по этому файлу за эти 2 недели?

Comment: А нет - опять поехало. На все латинские символы! Chrome portable.

Comment: результат:%252525%2525%25%F3035%252525%2525%25%F303%2525%25%E032%252525%2525%25%F3033%252525%2525%25%E0308

Comment: [mcve], please. Вход, ожидаемый выход, получаемый выход.

Comment: Входящий результат : ghbdtn;
Ожидаемый: привет;

Comment: Входящий результат : ghbdtn;Ожидаемый: привет;
Результат : привет (IE, Opera, FF, Chrome)
Результат в portable Chrome : зацикливание;
While trying to retrieve the URL: http://www.test.com/search/?search=%2525252525252525252525252525252525...........